# Можно ли создать таблицу с именем в mySQL в зависимости от внешней переменной?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

хочу сделать для каждого пользователя свою таблицу с постами, для этого выполняю следующие действия: когда пользователь хочет оставить запись то проверяется есть ли такая таблица (например user_posts_12, 12 - id пользователя). Если её нет, то создается следующим образом:

```
if (!isset($posts_table_is_exist)) {
        $users_posts_table_name = 'user_posts_' . $user_id;
        $create_posts_table = "CREATE Table $users_posts_table_name
        (
            id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            post_text TEXT() NOT NULL
        )";

        if (!$conn->query($create_posts_table)) die ('Error!');
    }
```

Но данный метод не срабатывает. Так вот кто знает как можно создать таблицу с именем на подобии user_posts_19, чтобы последняя цифра означала айди пользователя которому она принадлежит. Или если так нельзя сделать, тогда можете посоветовать как лучше хранить посты в базе для пользователей? Спасибо.

Comment: *как можно создать таблицу с именем на подобии user_posts_19, чтобы последняя цифра означала айди пользователя которому она принадлежит* Используя stored procedure и prepared statement. *хочу сделать для каждого пользователя свою таблицу с постами* Настоятельно советую отказаться от этой [censored] идеи. Одна таблица, с доп. полем `ID_user`.

Comment: Совсем не понятно какой в это вы закладываете смысл. Делайте по-человечески, таблица с постами , таблица с пользователями, JOIN, вот это всё...